# Botão pause player de música

Tags: c#

Sou um estagiário de programação e decidi fazer algo que nunca tentei antes, um player de música. Estou construindo as funções que cada botão deve fazer mas reparei que errei na parte do Pause fazendo com que na verdade o botão pare a música, queria muita ajuda para descobrir o meu erro.

```cs
//===================================================================================
//Começa a reproduzir a música escolhida
private void Iniciar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Código que reproduz uma música escolhida
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Biblioteca do Juan\Praticando WPF\musicPlayer\musicPlayer\Vessel.WAV";
    player.Play();

    //esconder botão iniciar
    Iniciar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    Pausar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

}

//===================================================================================
//Para a música que está sendo reproduzida
private void Pausar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Código que para a música que está rodando
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    player.Stop();

    //esconder butão pause
    Iniciar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Pausar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não use a classe [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.8) trata-se de uma funcionalidade bastante limitada e não dispõe do método `Pause` que você precisa.

Use a classe [`System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) que possui os métodos [`Play`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.play?view=netframework-4.8), [`Pause`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.pause?view=netframework-4.8) e [`Stop`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stop?view=netframework-4.8).

Para selecionar o arquivo a ser reproduzido você altera a propriedade [`Source`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source?view=netframework-4.8).

**Editado:**

A classe `MediaElement` só reproduz mídia se possuir representação da arvore XAML.

Então no ToolBox selecione um media element:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No XAML na linha `MediaElement` adicione a propriedade `Name="MediaElement1"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void Iniciar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //Essa linha pode ser colocada na inicialização. 
            //Está quai para mostrar sua necessidade.
            MediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

            MediaElement1.Stop();


            // Nescessário converter de string para uri
            MediaElement1.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            MediaElement1.Play();

            //mostra botão iniciar
            Iniciar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Pausar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

}


private void Pausar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    MediaElement1.Stop();

    //esconder butão pause
    Iniciar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Pausar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: tentei usar este código mas quando cheguei na parte do  "if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK" ele acusou que o ".OK" estava incorreto, assim como o  "media.Source = openFileDialog1.FileName;"  ele acusa um erro de código após o "="

Comment: Se seu programa for console `using System.Windows.Forms;`
Se for wpf coloque `using Microsoft.Win32;`

Comment: Opa Augusto, estou usando WPF msm mas já usava Win32, quando vou debugar a aplicação recebo dois erros 

1- sobre o ".OK" ( leia abaixo )

'bool?' não contém uma definição para 'OK' e nenhum método de extensão acessível 'OK' aceita um primeiro argumento do tipo 'bool?' pode ser encontrado (você está perdendo uma diretiva usando ou uma referência de assembly?)

2- sobre o openFileDialog1,FileName; (Abaixo tbm)

Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'System.Uri'

Comment: Troca `if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` por `if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog())`

Comment: continuo com 2 erros, acho que  invés de if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ou if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()).... eu deveria por if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true) e na linha abaixo um media.Open(new Uri(openFileDialog1.FileName));

Comment: se bem que continuaria errado por conta do "media.Open"

Comment: Fiz uma edição o código roda 100%.